# VBA userform - multiple column next row entry

Tags: excel, vba, multi-select, userform

I have created a userform to enter dates in for students and activities. A combobox (C1) will list student details. Column A is the name and B-F is other details that do not change (class, gender etc) - I have named this selection "student". I would like to select a student on column A and B-F should automatically be selected in the corresponding row. I have a combo box on my userform which shows the "student" list but struggling for each column to be entered onto the spreadsheet.

So I think there are two options - 
A) Create a formula to automatically enter details in B-F once A has been selected into other boxes on the user form.
B) Click submit which would add the entry for column A selection and B-F in the corresponding row. I currently use this formula but it is only entering column A (C1).

```
'Find the next empty row
Nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1


Cells(Nextrow, 1) = C1.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 2) = T1.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 3) = C2.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 4) = T2.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 5) = T3.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 6) = T4.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 7) = C3.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 8) = C4.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 9) = C5.Text
Cells(Nextrow, 10) = T5.Text
```

Thank you for any advice and assistance

Comment: You seem to say **row** when I think you want to say **column**. Can you go over your question and edit where needed?

Comment: Sorry I am new to VBA - I have adjusted. I hope this makes more sense!

Comment: Please could someone help with this formula?

Comment: Have you tried simplys populating one cell with the Student name, then using `VLOOKUP` to populate the rest of the columns?